# Subfigure alignments

Tags: subfloats

I am at the moment using the code:

`\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[][a]{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{d_vs_r0_varying_redshift_mass.pdf}}
\label{test1}
\subfloat[][b]{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{z_vs_r0_varying_redshift_mass.pdf}}
\label{test2}
\subfloat[][c]{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{d_vs_r0_varying_redshift_mass.pdf}}
\label{test3}
\end{figure}`

which gives me the following:

[image]

But **I would like to have Figure (a) on the top, with Figure (b) and Figure (c) at the bottom.** I am not able to find any website that deals with the alignments of subfigures. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Put a blank line after `\label{test1}`

Comment: @HarishKumar Wow!! இது ரொம்ப சிம்பிள் !! I didn't really think about this

Comment: Ah Ha. Tamil! where are you from?

Comment: @HarishKumar Chennai, but now in Nice, France. Doing my PhD in Astrophysics

Comment: Great!. Hope to meet you here often. All the best for Ph.D.

Comment: It is better to use the `width` than `scale`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `\par` (or a blank line) or `\\`. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\centering 
\subfloat[][a\label{test1}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}}\par  
\subfloat[][b\label{test2}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-b}}\qquad
\subfloat[][c\label{test1}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-c}}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\qquad` to introduce some space between the two bottom subfigures but you can use some other spacing.

Notice also that the correct placement of `\label` in `\subfloat` is *inside* the argument containing the caption (as in my example); otherwise, wrong strings will be picked for cross-references.

Comment: Well this was so easy, but didn't think about it.. Thanks

Comment: @ThePredator You're welcome! I updated my answer with some advise regarding the proper location for `\label`.

Comment: When I increase the scale to 0.5, the figures don't align the same way!! Is it possible to increase the scale a little bit? I am at the moment using 0.4

Comment: @ThePredator Whiat exactly should be the desired alignment? I think that, since this is not directly related to the original question, the best thing to do would be to open a fresh new question with this new requirement.