# Complex Subfigure layouts?

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying to use subfigure to arrange figures in the following way:

[image]

Is this possible using subfigure?

Comment: You can try \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}....\end{minipage}

Comment: Take a look at the `floatrow` package.

Comment: agree, nice example is here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230425/subfigure-alignments?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newdimen\figrasterwd
\figrasterwd\textwidth

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \parbox{\figrasterwd}{
    \parbox{.6\figrasterwd}{%
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=8cm]{imageA}}%'height=8cm' is needed for this example only and can be dropped when using it with actual images
    }
    \hskip1em
    \parbox{.3\figrasterwd}{%
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{imageB}}
      \vskip1em
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{imageC}}  
    }
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]