# Complex subfigure grid

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

I would like to arrange four subfigures into a 2-by-2 grid, where the grid element heights vary; something like this:

```
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|       c)
|------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
   a)     |----------|
          |----------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
   b)          d)
```

[image]

Is this possible? I tried to adapt [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304830/168708) for a similar question, but could not get it to work for my complex requirements.

---

**Update**

Following some very useful answers, I realise I did not precisely specify my requirements. In particular, the sum of the heights for each column are not equal. I thus want to align the bases of each column, like this:

```
|------|  
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|       c)
|------|  
|------|  |----------|
   a)     |----------|
          |----------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
|------|  |----------|
   b)          d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the linked solution is actually quite straight-forward – just add the desired heights:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \parbox{.3\textwidth}{%
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=4cm]{imageA}}
      \vskip1em
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2cm]{imageB}}
    }
    \hskip1em
    \parbox{.3\textwidth}{%
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2cm]{imageC}}
      \vskip1em
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=4cm]{imageD}} 
    }
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** If the bases of the columns shall be aligned, this can be achieved by specifying the vertical alignment of the parboxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \parbox[b]{.3\textwidth}{%
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=4cm]{imageA}}
      \vskip1em
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2cm]{imageB}}
    }
    \hskip1em
    \parbox[b]{.3\textwidth}{%
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=2cm]{imageC}}
      \vskip1em
      \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize, height=4cm]{imageD}} 
    }
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible for the column bases to align if the sum of the subfigure heights in each column are not equal (please see my edit)?

Comment: @Adam: yes, it is possible. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using minipage environments on the right most column images.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=8cm]{imageA}}\quad
        \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
            \vspace{-8cm}
            \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{imageA}}
        \end{minipage}\\[12pt] 
        \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{imageA}}
        \quad
        \begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
            \vspace{-6cm}
            \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=6cm]{imageA}}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to modify your answer so the bases of the columns align, given the sum of heights in each column are unequal (as per my edit)?

Answer (score 3):

This layout is quite easy to obtain with `\valign`.

The command `\subcaptionpartial` has the syntax

```
\subcaptionpartial[<list entry>]{<subcaption>}{<image>}
```

and, as in `\subcaptionbox`, the `\label` should go in the first mandatory argument. If missing, the optional argument is taken to be the same as the first mandatory argument, as usual for `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{subcaptioncolumns}{}
 {\def\\{\unskip\unskip\cr\noalign{\hspace{1em}}}\valign\bgroup\vfil##\cr}
 {\unskip\unskip\crcr\egroup}
\NewDocumentCommand{\subcaptionpartial}{O{#2}mm}{%
  \hbox{\subcaptionbox[#1]{#2}{#3}}\medskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subcaptioncolumns}
\subcaptionpartial{\label{one}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=6cm]{example-image}%
}
\subcaptionpartial{\label{two}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=3cm]{example-image}%
}
\\
\subcaptionpartial{\label{three}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{example-image}%
}
\subcaptionpartial{\label{four}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{example-image}%
}
\end{subcaptioncolumns}

\caption{Whatever}\label{full}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]