# Composition of multiple figures

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, figure-placement

I'm trying to compose multiple figure into a singular `figure` block. I would like to obtain something like what in the picture.
[image]

Comment: More possible duplicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304826/complex-subfigure-layouts https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87975/one-figure-having-two-columns-of-subfigures-the-left-column-has-one-image-and-t https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288141/arrange-images-as-tables-or-subfigure-or-some-other-layout